# PyDev 5.9.2 runtime error in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using PyDev installed as an Eclipse extension (through the update site) on Windows 7 and WinPython 3.6.0.1. I can run code just fine even though the syntax checker is broken, i.e., marks as error "Undefined variable: print" lines as simple as

```
print("hello")
```

I think the issue is connected with this error I get in the error log as soon as I start Eclipse:

```
Error creating python process - exited before creating sockets - exitValue = (1).
```

This is the Exception stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating python process - exited before creating sockets - exitValue = (1).
ProcessInfo:

 - Executed: C:\tools\winpython\3.6.0.1\python-3.6.0.amd64\python.exe -u C:\Portables\Eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.9.2.201708151115\pysrc\pycompletionserver.py 55270

 - Environment:
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
[... list of all the environment variables ...]

 - Working Dir:
C:\Portables\Eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.9.2.201708151115\pysrc

 - OS:
Windows 7

 - Std output:


 - Err output:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Portables\Eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.9.2.201708151115\pysrc\pycompletionserver.py", line 13, in <module>

    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants import IS_JYTHON

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pydevd_bundle'



    at org.python.pydev.core.log.Log.log(Log.java:54)

    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.shell.AbstractShell.startIt(AbstractShell.java:290)

    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.shell.ShellsContainer.getServerShell(ShellsContainer.java:232)

    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.shell.ShellsContainer.getServerShell(ShellsContainer.java:165)

    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.shell.AbstractShell.getServerShell(AbstractShell.java:222)

    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.modules.CompiledModule.createTokensFromServer(CompiledModule.java:372)

    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.modules.CompiledModule.<init>(CompiledModule.java:176)

    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.SystemModulesManager.getBuiltinModule(SystemModulesManager.java:332)

    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.SystemModulesManager.getBuiltinModule(SystemModulesManager.java:1)

    at org.python.pydev.ui.interpreters.AbstractInterpreterManager.getBuiltinMod(AbstractInterpreterManager.java:146)

    at org.python.pydev.ui.interpreters.AbstractInterpreterManager.getBuiltinCompletions(AbstractInterpreterManager.java:118)

    at org.python.pydev.plugin.nature.PythonNature.getBuiltinCompletions(PythonNature.java:1126)

    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.AbstractASTManager.getBuiltinComps(AbstractASTManager.java:1801)

    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.AbstractASTManager.getBuiltinCompletions(AbstractASTManager.java:1787)

    at com.python.pydev.analysis.scopeanalysis.AbstractScopeAnalyzerVisitor.<init>(AbstractScopeAnalyzerVisitor.java:151)

    at com.python.pydev.analysis.visitors.OccurrencesVisitor.<init>(OccurrencesVisitor.java:105)

    at com.python.pydev.analysis.OccurrencesAnalyzer.analyzeDocument(OccurrencesAnalyzer.java:50)

    at com.python.pydev.analysis.builder.AnalysisBuilderRunnable.doAnalysis(AnalysisBuilderRunnable.java:271)

    at com.python.pydev.analysis.builder.AbstractAnalysisBuilderRunnable.run(AbstractAnalysisBuilderRunnable.java:162)

    at org.python.pydev.core.concurrency.RunnableAsJobsPoolThread$1.run(RunnableAsJobsPoolThread.java:140)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

So, apparently the error is this

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pydevd_bundle'
```

I tried reinstalling PyDev (it looks like the installation might be broken), but to no avail. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have actually found the issue. I discovered the WinPython distribution I installed was "WinPython Zero", which comes with no additional packages. I uninstalled it and installed the "default" WinPython; now the debugger is working as expected. I suppose then there's some library needed to enable debugging. Maybe a more informative error message would help here, as this one I got really doesn't say much.

Funny thing, that's exactly what happens in PyCharm too: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24198